# ng build command builds the development environment as default instead of building production

Tags: angular, deployment, build, production, ng-build

when I run the "ng build" command in a terminal, it builds the development environment, not the production environment.

If I run the "ng build --prod" it works fine. But without changing any default behavior, it is building the development environment.

If I run the "npm run build" command it correctly builds the production environment.

I want to know why this happens and how to fix this? I have provided the package.json and angular.json files below:

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "..........",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"{,!(node_modules|dist|build|coverage)/**/}*.{js,jsx,ts,json}\"",
    "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run prettier",
    "extract-i18n": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/{en,nl,fr,es,it,de}.json --format namespaced-json --sort"
  },
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run pre-commit"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^11.1.0",
    "@coreui/angular": "~2.11.1",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@coreui/icons-angular": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^2.1.2",
    "@uiowa/digit-only": "^2.2.3",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^25.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.37",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.0",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-avatar": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-editor": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-translate-cache": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^4.9.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.1.0",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.184",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "husky": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.13",
    "npm": "= 6.11.0"
  }
}
```

**angular.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": ["src/assets", "src/assets/i18n"],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/free.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/dist/styles/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["./node_modules", "src/scss"]
            },
            "scripts": ["node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.js"],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["lodash"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/free.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/dist/styles/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["./node_modules"]
            },
            "assets": ["src/assets", "src/favicon.ico"]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ng-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ng",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Using 'npm run build' will execute the 'build' script defined in your 'package.json' and in your build script you have 'ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress' which is the reason why the production build is triggered

Comment: Angular 12 and higher use the production build by default. Previous versions default to the development build. You are using Angular 11.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in angular.json , in the build section:

```
"defaultConfiguration": "production"
```

You do not have a dev section in Angular.json, I added one for you(check the settings!!) :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": ["src/assets", "src/assets/i18n"],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/free.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/dist/styles/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["./node_modules", "src/scss"]
            },
            "scripts": ["node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.js"],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["lodash"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
        "development": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
        
          }
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/free.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/dist/styles/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["./node_modules"]
            },
            "assets": ["src/assets", "src/favicon.ico"]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ng-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ng",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```